# YII2 Unable to write right url to an action in different modules

Tags: yii2-basic-app

Have installed Yii2 today. I have struggled to redirect to a module action without success for over 6 hours now.

project\app\modules\instClients\controllers\InstTypesController\actionCreate

Index file is in project

return $this->redirect(['instClients/instTypes/create'])
in siteController/actionIndex creates the url
http://localhost/project/index.php?r=instClients/instTypes/create.

http://localhost/project/index.php?r=instClients/instTypes/create returns Not Found (#404) Page not found.

How do I redirect to this action, Or what is the correct url I should use to access action create in instTypesController in module instClients, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make yourself clear first.. and include your action code and view code

Comment: `enable preety url` and the answer i gave you will work properly.. From your link i am guessing that you havent given any controller in the link... URL works like this yourprojectname/controller/actionmethod where actionmethod goes the name of methog without `action` word

Comment: return $this->redirect(['instClients/instTypes/create'])  creates the url http://localhost/project/index.php?r=instClients/instTypes/create i do not understand why error #404 page not found. Or what is the correct url I should use to access action create in instTypesController in module instClients, please?

Comment: In which method you are using this `return $this->redirect(['instClients/instTypes/create'])`

Comment: show your directory structure from `instClients` and enable pretty url.

Comment: Thanks so far. i've enabled pretty url. the structure is project\app\modules\instClients\controllers\InstTypesController\actionCreate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think it also depended on your url mapping. are you check out yii2 debugger for selected url mapping and it's right url mapping. e.g:

```
'<_m:[\w\-]+>/<_c:[\w\-]+>/<_a:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<_m>/<_c>/<_a>',
                '<_m:[\w\-]+>/<_c:[\w\-]+>/<_a:[\w\-]+>/<item:\w+>' => '<_m>/<_c>/<_a>',
                '<_m:[\w\-]+>/<_c:[\w\-]+>/<_a:[\w\-]+>/<sort:\w+>' => '<_m>/<_c>/<_a>',
                '<_m:[\w\-]+>/<_c:[\w\-]+>/<_a:[\w\-]+>/<sort:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<_m>/<_c>/<_a>',
                '<_m:[\w\-]+>/<_c:[\w\-]+>/<_a:[\w\-]+>' => '<_m>/<_c>/<_a>',
                '<_m:[\w\-]+>/<_c:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<_m>/<_c>/view',
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect from a page to another page action than in the `href` you don't have to write `action` in the link

For example if you want to redirect to action named `actionCreate` in `UserController` than your href will be something like this

```
/user/create
```

Depending on your path from where you are redirecting

I hope that answers your question